# Entity framework cached result

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I got a singleton container of my container entity.

```
Container containerEntity = Container;
```

everything run ok till I try to get the value of a intermediate class acting like a normal table, happen that I get old values I need to restart the server to get fresh values or instantiate the container entity again, (Breaking the singleton), my question is how can I get fresh value with the same instance created time ago not with a new instance of container object.

the weirdest thing is that with others tables I got fresh values just happen with that intermediate table ( intermediate table acting like a normal table ).

```
table
--------------
table_1_id
table_2_id
value_now
value_prev
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the lifecycle of your `DbContext`? You're not meant to keep instances of that object around after a single transaction is over.

Comment: I'm not using code first, ModelFirst

Comment: Why does that matter? They're just different workflows, the underlying stuff remains the same.

Comment: ok what you propose me to do? I don't what to make an instance on every request.

Comment: For starters, answer my questions about the lifecycle of your context object and the container entity. Entity Framework doesn't support retaining either indefinitely - load a new `Container` from a new `DbContext` everytime you need the current values of its properties **or** its dependent entities. That you don't want to do this is irrelevant, that's how the framework works - it will not ever support "live-updating" data from the database.

Comment: The closest you could use is [`ObjectContext.Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.refresh.aspx), but it'd still be an abuse of the framework, you'd still get bugs elsewhere, and it wouldn't perform better because the method hits the database anyway.

Comment: I will try with ObjectContext.Refresh() and see what happen. I don't mean live updating I just want to use the same instance.

Comment: And I maintain this is a bad idea with no practical advantages. At least consider using a new `ObjectContext` each time, making it clear the singleton is a detached entity.

Comment: I think too much on performance but make an instance of a entotyContainer it's cost too much isn't it?

Comment: Why would it? Also, you're working with a database. The expensive operation is the I/O involved, everything else is likely gravy. Also: premature optimization etc. Worry about performance where you're losing it, not where you imagine you'll be losing it.